# How add a a number to a variable in batch

Tags: batch-file

Hey I'm working on a project of mine in batch. yes I know its bad but I'm using it anyways. I was trying to make an updating inventory system when I ran into this problem. I was trying to add a set number E.X 1 to a variable like this:

```
@echo off
set var=0
echo I will add these numbers from var+1
set /a var=%var%+1
pause
echo var
pause
```

what is the problem?

Comment: There is a simpler form to add to a var with `Set /a var+=1` and also with set /a there is no need to enclose the var wih percent signs (aside from ! and delayed expanasion) I suggest reading`help set`

Comment: `set /?` isn't going to mention the alternate variation of `set /a` that you're talking about.

Comment: thanks that helps a lot. I got my program working! thanks again

Comment: @SomethingDark cited from Set /? `Any non-numeric strings in the
expression are treated as environment variable names whose values are
converted to numbers before using them.  If an environment variable name
is specified but is not defined in the current environment, then a value
of zero is used.  This allows you to do arithmetic with environment
variable values without having to type all those % signs to get their
values.`

Answer (score 2):

To show the *value* of the variable `var`, you need

```
echo %var%
```